# Shockwave flash has crashed on chrome on mac while accessing vSphere web client

Tags: macos, google-chrome, web, client, vsphere

Environment:

macOS Sierra 10.12.6, Chrome 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Trying to load vSphere web client crashes with "Shockwave Flash has crashed" error.

Tried following but none helped so far.

1. Removed latest Google Chrome PepperFlash plugin 27.0.0.170 and replaced it with 27.0.0.159 in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/PepperFlash.
2. Enabled running flashes in chrome and added exceptions to the URLs of vSphere
3. Restarted chrome browser

As a workaround, tried firefox browser to access vSphere web client but even there got the "The adobe flash plugin has crashed" error.

Same vSphere web client works from Mac thats of 2014 but running same environment as above. This is strange that same Mac Version and Chrome version combo works on 2014 mac but not in 2016 mac.

Can someone share any ideas that could solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions from vmware [1] for installing an older version for Firefox worked for me on MacOS 10.12.6 on a 2017 Mac.  I did not try to get it working under Chrome.

[1] https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2151945https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2151945

Answer (score 0):

You could reinstall the archived versions of adobe flash to 27.0.0.159.

- https://forums.adobe.com/message/9892441#9892441

After that, it will be work. See the above link to figure it out.